Why does my component never get the property value that I'm setting?
I have a react component and a convenience function for printing it down wrapped in an ant design <Col> and <Form.Item> for easy use in form building, but no matter what gets passed for the "value" property on the <YesNoColumn>, it always renders as if it were passed true.  Chatgpt just suggested the useEffect addition, but that didn't fix anything.
Can anyone help me out with why my component won't render the [false] variant?  It displays the green checkmark even when I manually set its value with <YesNoIcon value={false} />
export const YesNoIcon = ({ value = true, fontSize = '24px', onChange }) => {
const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(value);
useEffect(() => {
    setToggled(value);
}, [value]);
const triggerChange = (changedValue: boolean) => {
    onChange?.(changedValue);
};
const toggle = () => {
    setToggled(!toggled);
    triggerChange(!toggled);
}
return toggled ?
    <CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: 'green', fontSize: fontSize }} onClick={toggle} onChange={toggle} /> :
    <CloseCircleFilled style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: fontSize }} onClick={toggle} onChange={toggle} />
};

export const graphicalYesNoField = (name: string, label: string, initially: boolean = true, columnSpan: number = 8, fontSize: string = '24px'): React.ReactNode => {
    return <Col span={columnSpan}>
        <Form.Item name={name} label={label}>
            <YesNoIcon value={initially} fontSize={fontSize} />
        </Form.Item>
    </Col>
};

Note that this is only a problem for me when I'm trying to show the "Create New" form rather than an "Update Existing".  When I'm updating an existing record, the form sets these <YesNoIcon> form items appropriately based on what's coming back from useForm().  It's only when I'm creating a new record that it just always falls back on the default value, even when I'm explicitly setting it to false for one of them.
The actual details form component that I'm using for both creating a new user record and updating an existing one is below:
const UserDetails = () => {
const { saveButtonProps, formProps, formLoading, queryResult } = useForm();
return (
    <Edit isLoading={formLoading}
        saveButtonProps={saveButtonProps}
        breadcrumb={true}>
        <Form {...formProps} layout='vertical'>
            <Form.Item hidden name="id" />
            <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
                {simpleInputField('lastName', 'Last Name')}
                {simpleInputField('firstName', 'First Name')}
                {simpleInputField('middleName', 'Middle Name')}
            </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
                {simpleInputField('suffix', 'Suffix')}
            </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
                {simpleInputField('userName', 'User Name', 12)}
                {simpleInputField('email', 'Email', 12)}
            </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
                {graphicalYesNoField('active', 'Active')}
                {graphicalYesNoField('neverExpires', 'Never Expires', false)}
            </Row>
        </Form>
    </Edit>
)
}


More info about your  Create New form and Update Existing form would be nice

Updated the question to include the component responsible for rendering the create/edit form itself.

Change graphicalYesNoField to an actual component and let react render and control it. After that if it doesn't work we can continue debugging it.

Changing graphicalYesNoField to a component ended up breaking it such that the form never submitted anything for 'active' or 'neverExpires' aside from what the initial value was.  It still toggled between icons fine, but the form data never updated.

When I reverted the changes and then added initialValue to the Form.Item, it finally started working the way I want it to.  I get console warnings that the initial value is already set by form, but I hesitate to care about that.  I've spent hours trying to get something that should be dirt simple done and it feels like I had to conquer Rome just to get to this point....

could you provide a codesandbox which to show you problem.

Change your toggle function to
const toggle = () => {
    setToggled(prev => {
        triggerChange(!prev);
        return !prev;
    });
}

It's asynchronously executed and that way you can be sure that the previous value of toggled is used for setting the new one.
Additionaly you can remove the useEffect call as your component YesNoIcon receives value in the object which is passed as a parameter and toggled is initialized with value anyway. The change of toggled triggers the rerendering, so the useEffect call is not necessary in this case.
But you may have to ensure that the containing component is rerendered when the passed value changes (just use useState there too for holding value). That will then also rerender YesNoIcon.
EDIT:
Try changing this
export const graphicalYesNoField = (name: string, label: string, initially: boolean = true, columnSpan: number = 8, fontSize: string = '24px'): React.ReactNode => ...

to this
export const GraphicalYesNoField = ({name: string, label: string, initially: boolean = true, columnSpan: number = 8, fontSize: string = '24px'}): React.ReactNode => ...

(Note the uppercase G in GraphicalYesNoField and it takes an object as parameter and assigns the contained variables via destructuring.)
and this
<Form {...formProps} layout='vertical'>
    <Form.Item hidden name="id" />
    <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('lastName', 'Last Name')}
        {simpleInputField('firstName', 'First Name')}
        {simpleInputField('middleName', 'Middle Name')}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('suffix', 'Suffix')}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('userName', 'User Name', 12)}
        {simpleInputField('email', 'Email', 12)}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {graphicalYesNoField('active', 'Active')}
        {graphicalYesNoField('neverExpires', 'Never Expires', false)}
    </Row>
</Form>

to this
<Form {...formProps} layout='vertical'>
    <Form.Item hidden name="id" />
    <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('lastName', 'Last Name')}
        {simpleInputField('firstName', 'First Name')}
        {simpleInputField('middleName', 'Middle Name')}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('suffix', 'Suffix')}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        {simpleInputField('userName', 'User Name', 12)}
        {simpleInputField('email', 'Email', 12)}
    </Row><Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        <GraphicalYesNoField name="active" label="Active"/>
        <GraphicalYesNoField name="neverExpires" label="Never Expires" initially={false}/>
    </Row>
</Form>

GraphicalYesNoField is a real component now. Consider making simpleInputField a real component too, so your code is more consistent.

Tried this but it didn't seem to have any effect on the initial display of the component.

@JDS I updated my answer, found another possible reason why your code is not working as expected.
